# Plx error: #INVALID_ARGUMENT BAD_QUERY: Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL:

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to filter the date inside the google sheets connecting with the PLX, but I'm not being able to do it and I receive the error **Plx error: #INVALID_ARGUMENT BAD_QUERY: Argument type mismatch in function EQUAL: 'admin_review_date' is type int32, '29/07/2021' is type string**

Notes:

${TEST} relates to the cell "Aux!C2"

and for the ${TEST} I have tried to filter the data in different ways:

> . =DATEVALUE(C3)
>
> . =((Text(C3,"YYYY-MM-DD")-25569)*86400)/0.000001
>
> . '29/07/2021'

```
SELECT
  admin_review_date,admin_review_week
 
FROM
 
  data_resource


WHERE admin_site = "Place"
     and admin_vendor = "Company"
     and admin_review_date = ${TEST}
     
ORDER BY admin_review_date desc

LIMIT 10000
```

But in none of them I can't be able to filter by the date.

Unfortunately, I can't share a trix because it's client data.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by PLX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify what you mean by PLX. Your trying to case a string into an int32 field. Your `admin_review_date` is an Integer. Perhaps Unix Timestamp.

Comment: Hello Aerials, the PLX is the Data connectors inside google sheets that are BigQuery and PLX. I'll check related to the Unix timestamp, thanks a lot

Comment: thanks for your comment Aerials, the Unix timestamp was the solution to solve my issue